# VSCode Change Color of console.log()

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode version 1.56.1 and I'd like to change my `console.log()` color from this:[image]

to this:
[image]

Is there any way I can change only this instead of changing the colour of other variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found how to do this to console. If you want to do it yourself, in your settings.json file type:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "[Default Dark+]": { // You can enter your own theme here as well
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": "support.variable",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#4EC9B0",
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. I hate when they make changes to symbol colors that I've grown used to. Also, there is a missing closing brace `}` at the end of your example.